# All subdomains blocked by Google SafeBrowsing

Tags: google, safe-browsing-filter

GoogleSafebrowsing seems to have blacklisted one of my domain names, along with all its subdomains. It is visible on [this google search page](https://www.google.com/search?q=site:renegat.net&gws_rd=cr&ei=vXeXVtXYDorPa9WXqoAH).

I'm a seasoned linux system administrator, I've checked my server several times, and I didn't find anything suspicious on it.

Of course, I could be wrong, but the point is that Google Webmaster Tools doesn't give me any extra detail: the displayed symptom is "Unknown Malware", and the list of exemple URLs is empty, which gives absolutely no hint at all...

I asked for a review from within Webmaster Tools, which came back negative.

The fact that all the subdomains are affected is rather strange. Some of them are just a static html page, without even any javascript or css.

I made a [post](https://goo.gl/azXaxJ) on Google's Webmaster Central Help Forum, but didn't get any additional clue. All I got back is a value judgment on the content.

Which solutions do I have to either have more details on why Google did block my whole domain, or to reach a real support at Google?

Comment: Could it possible be due to the fact your running Apaache Httpd 2.2.22 ?

Comment: Also your webpage "yo" is not valid HTML.[w3c validator page](https://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A%2F%2Frenegat.net%2F&charset=%28detect+automatically%29&doctype=Inline&ss=1&group=0&verbose=1&user-agent=W3C_Validator%2F1.3+http%3A%2F%2Fvalidator.w3.org%2Fservices)

Comment: It's not the version of apache: other sites using the same server aren't affected. Concerning the invalid HTML, I don't see why it would be considered harmfull, neither why it would impact other subdomains.

Comment: the way your incorrect HTML page is constructed can mirror how an exploit abuses a website (e.a. it looks like it has been tampered with).

Comment: One minor detail which may have something to do with it, I noticed that your server is returning an ETag even when instructed not to cache. Maybe not but that definitely shouldn't be so.

Comment: @LvB I fixed the html on this specific page, and asked for a review again.

Comment: @JonathanGray I'm relying on apache defaults on this one, so it would be pretty surprising if it were the cause - and returning ETags doesn't mean the cache has been use

Comment: @ClaudeBrisson I'm afraid your html is still not valid. htlm is not a known tag, html on the other would work.

Comment: @LvB ah, you're right... anyway, it wasn't the reason, see my own response.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Solved. One of the subdomains had been hacked and contained several javascript injections.

Some interesting facts:

1. it's rather surprising that google blacklisted all the other subdomains, I wonder if it's a systematic behavior or not.
2. the example harmful URLs list given in the WebmasterTools is empty for the other subdomains, but when you ask for a review, which fails, the `View Examples` button in the mail **does** list some problematic URLs from the hacked site even if it is not the one you asked the review for.

As a conclusion, while I'm grateful to Google for having detected and filtered the injection, I regret a bit that the blacklisting algorithm exhibits a domain-wide behavior, and that the Webmaster Tools interface is unable to explain that a specific subdomain has been blacklisted because of a problem in another subdomain.

Answer (score 0):

> The fact that all the subdomains are affected is rather strange. Some of them are just a static html page, without even any javascript or css.

It is hard to know what really is going on but it might be that your server is hacked like described in [Ongoing malware attack targeting Apache hijacks 20,000 sites](http://arstechnica.com/security/2013/04/exclusive-ongoing-malware-attack-targeting-apache-hijacks-20000-sites/) which would affect all sites. It might also be some injected script inside on of the static Javascript files you serve on the pages. Or it might be something else.

Comment: Other domains on the same server aren't affected. I just checked for the Darkleech infection with [a script provided by arstechnica](http://goo.gl/HNOVI9), and the system is clean. And precisely, the point is to be able to know **why** the sites are considered harmful by Google.